# Disabling sessions in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

Is it normal for a Zend Framework Application to **always** start a session?  I recently moved my sessions into the DB and it was easier to notice that no matter what page is hit, say even the home page, a session is created.

I've searched high and low in my code to see if I'm bootstrapping a session to start, but it isn't very obvious why this is.  I just want to know if this is normal behavior or I'm overlooking something.

I still want sessions for areas that the user logs in, of course, but for everyone else, it is  extra overhead.

Thanks, ya'll!

Comment: I don't know ZF, but have you narrowed down which part of the library is starting a session? If not, search for `session_start` in the whole of the ZF library, and see which of those components you're actually using.

Comment: you have setup a controller plugin with Zend_Auth perhaps?

Comment: `stagl [/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend] $ grep -r "session_start" .
./Session.php:            throw new Zend_Session_Exception('session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()');
./Session.php:            $startedCleanly = session_start();`

Comment: Do you have anything session related in your bootstrap class or application.ini?

Comment: Yeah, I did.  But I've removed them...  This is getting strange.   I'm going to go ahead and say that normal Zend Framework apps should **not** be starting session then?

Comment: OK, turns out it was wordpress of all things.  I have a little library for wordpress that grabs the latest posting and shows it on the home page.  I guess initializing the wordpress library starts a session.  I'll be digging into that code later.  Sorry for the goose chase, everyone!

Comment: hum :( you didnt mentioned your using wordpress too...

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing any `Zend_Session_Namespace`, you are using a session. If this namespace object is used inside a `Zend_Controller_Plugin` that is called in any of the stages of routing (e.g. routeStartup, routeShutdown, preDispatch etc...), as it would be useful for the user authentication, that will ALWAYS be using the session.